# how i check is_unique on two columns in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter-4

I have DB where there are 2 columns, one is 'Day' and the other is 'Timing'. I need to check while adding a new schedule, ex:- is Monday '6.00 am to 10.00 am' already set or not. Any validation for this kind of Condition?

is_unique suitable for this condition? if yes then please suggest how?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Share your table schema in a textual format as well.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa I tried to implement is_unique. But it is not helpful for 2 different columns

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa 

id         day                timing  exercise
1            Monday       6.00 am to 8.00 am  Cardio 

this is how my DB tbl is

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72768806/edit) and share what you've tried so far.

Comment: How are you performing form validation? Are you using the `app\Config\Validation.php` class or the controller's `$this->validate(...)` method, or are you validating data in the model?  Which is which?

Comment: Is it not possible to run a query to check this?

Comment: Out of the box, form validation isn't going to do anything to help you look at what values might be in the database.